# Apache Camel: errorHandler vs onException?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, apache-camel

What's the difference between:

```
<camel:errorHandler id="deadLetterErrorHandler" type="DeadLetterChannel" 
        deadLetterUri="log:dead">

<camel:camelContext errorHandlerRef="deadLetterErrorHandler">
    ...
</camel:camelContext>
```

And:

```
<onException>
    ...
</onException>
```

According to [this article](http://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html), using them both in conjunction is a "powerful combination". How so? What roles do they each individual assume, and how do they complement each other?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `errorHandler` is used to handle any uncaught `Exception` that gets thrown during the routing and processing of a message.  Conversely, `onException` is used to handle specific `Exception` types when they are thrown.  Check out [this article](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html) to see how to use `onException`.

Comment: So if I write `onException(Throwable.class)` I've basically implemented the `errorHandler`?

Comment: I'm new to camel but as for me it lacks support for per-processor error handler - handler that will catch any exception. Sample code:
~~~
<br/>
<pre/>
from("direct:a") 
  .unmarshall(new MyDataFormat("param1"))
    .perProcessorErrorHandler(deadLetterQueue("log:foo"))
  .process(myProcessor)
    .perProcessorErrorHandler(deadLetterQueue("log:bar"))
  .to(myAnotherProcessor)
    .perProcessorErrorHandler(deadLetterQueue("log:baz"))
~~~
this allows me not to think about types of exceptions for each processor

Answer (score 4):

If the action you need to perform for each type of exception is different, use onException. It lets you define error handling on a per exception basis.

`onException(xxxException.class).to("activemq:xxxFailed");`
`onException(yyyException.class).to("activemq:yyyFailed");`

If you just need a generic handler, go with errorHandler. For all type of errors, the same processing will be performed.